# focusout not triggering outside of element, unless element is clicked once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've added some JavaScript that makes the arrow button face up when it is clicked, but in reality, the CSS class is removed off the first one, and replaced with another that has the arrow facing down.

I want it to revert to its default down position when i focus-out off the button, but it seems to not be working as expected. i have to physically click the button again, than click outside anywhere in the document for it to focus out. Not sure whats going on but here is code

```js
var firstBut = document.getElementById('firstbutton');
var secBut = document.getElementById('secbutton');

firstBut.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tristique mi non dui euismod sodales. Fusce vehicula libero in orci eleifend tristique.");
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(para);
  clickme();
});

function clickme() {
  secBut.classList.add('active');
  firstBut.style.display = 'none';
  secBut.style.display = 'inline-block';
};

function resetClick() {
  secBut.style.display = 'none';
  firstBut.style.display = 'inline-block';
};
```

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstbutton {
  border-radius: 80px;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#secbutton {
  border-radius: 80px;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black;
  width: 250px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'>
  <h1>What we do, here at X construction </h1>
  <button type="button" id='firstbutton'>&#8595;</button>
  <button type="button" onfocusout="resetClick()" id='secbutton'>&#8593;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, from what I understand, this is your objective:

1. By default, the button is facing down.
2. When clicked only, it must be facing up (not when its moused over)
3. And when you move out of the button area, it must face down

If that's the case, there is a much easier solution with like just 2 lines of javascript code.

The syntax for button down is `&#8595;` & the syntax for an upward button is `&#8593;`.

So, the idea is that when only the button is clicked, we change the `innerHTML` to an up arrow and when the mouse leaves the button, it changes it back to downward arrow.

Try this:

```js
function btnClick() {
  document.getElementById("firstbutton").innerHTML = "&#8593;"; 
}

function btnOut(){
    document.getElementById("firstbutton").innerHTML = "&#8595;"; 
}
```

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstbutton {
  border-radius: 80px;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 28px;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black;
  width: 250px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'>
  <h1>What we do, here at X construction </h1>
  <button type="button" onmouseout="btnOut()" onclick="btnClick()" id='firstbutton'>&#8595;</button>
</div>
```

ps: I've removed away unwanted html & javascript

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that making the second button visible doesn't give it focus. You can't get a `focusout` event if the element was never focused in the first place. That's why you have to click on the button again.

You can have the `clickme()` function give the second button focus when it makes it visible. Do this with `secBut.focus()`.

```js
var firstBut = document.getElementById('firstbutton');
var secBut = document.getElementById('secbutton');

firstBut.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tristique mi non dui euismod sodales. Fusce vehicula libero in orci eleifend tristique.");
  para.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(para);
  clickme();
});

function clickme() {
  secBut.classList.add('active');
  firstBut.style.display = 'none';
  secBut.style.display = 'inline-block';
  secBut.focus();
};

function resetClick() {
  secBut.style.display = 'none';
  firstBut.style.display = 'inline-block';
};
```

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

#firstbutton {
  border-radius: 80px;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 28px;
}

#secbutton {
  border-radius: 80px;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid black;
  width: 250px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'>
  <h1>What we do, here at X construction </h1>
  <button type="button" id='firstbutton'>&#8595;</button>
  <button type="button" onfocusout="resetClick()" id='secbutton'>&#8593;</button>
</div>
```

A better design might be to keep the same button, but just change its text to change the direction of the arrow.